# Beginner making a lotto program with no cins, can't figure out how to compare all numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, variable-assignment

Here are my assignment instructions:

> You are to write a program which will do the Lotto.
>
> The lotto consists of 5 numbers from 1-70 and a power ball from
>   numbers 1-30.
>
> The first 5 numbers should not repeat  (same for the winning numbers).
>   The power ball can repeat with any of the first 5 numbers.
>
> You are going to purchase 10,000 lotto tickets.  Each ticket has 6
>   numbers (5 num and 1 pow).
>
> Give each ticket random numbers, and compare to the winning numbers
>   (winning numbers generated only once).
>
> Match the 5 numbers and the power ball number and you win the jackpot!
>
> Match 5 numbers only and you win $1,000,000.
>
> Match 4 numbers only and you win $50,000.
>
> Match 3 numbers only and you win $7.
>
> Match under 3 numbers, but you got the power ball and you win $4.
>
> anything else wins nothing.

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int nums[6];
    int powerball;
    nums[5] = powerball;
    int win5p;
    int win5;
    int win4;
    int win3;
    int winu3p;

    for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        cout << "The generated numbers are:" << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
        {
            nums[x] = rand() % 71 + 1;
            cout << nums[x] << endl;
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
        {
            cout << "The generated powerball is:" << endl;
            powerball = rand() % 31 + 1;
            cout << powerball << endl;
        }
    }

    int compnums[6];
    int comppowerball;
    compnums[5] = comppowerball;

    for (int x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    {
        cout << "The winning numbers are:" << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
        {
            compnums[x] = rand() % 71 + 1;
            cout << compnums[x] << endl;
        }

        cout << "The winning powerball is:" << endl;
        for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
        {
            comppowerball = rand() % 31 + 1;
            cout << comppowerball << endl;
        }

        for (int x = 0; x <= 5; x++)
        {
            if ((nums[0] == compnums[x]) && (nums[1] == compnums[x]) && (nums[2] == compnums[x]) && (nums[3] == compnums[x]) && (nums[4] == compnums[x]) && (nums[5] == compnums[x]) && (powerball == comppowerball))
            {
            win5p = true;
            }
            if ((nums[0] == compnums[x]) && (nums[1] == compnums[x]) && (nums[2] == compnums[x]) && (nums[3] == compnums[x]) && (nums[4] == compnums[x]) && (nums[5] == compnums[x]))
            {
            win5 = true;
            }
            // I get lost right here. I don't even know if I'm doing any of this correctly.
        }
    }
```

Yeah. If anyone could please help me, I'd be the happiest girl ever.
I have 10 instead of 10,000 tickets so it is easier for me to look through when debugging, but it will have to be 10,000 when I am finished. Matching lotto numbers can be in any place, so if numbers[1] matches with compnumbers[4], it still would be counted as matching. Please ask any questions you need to ask, I know this is a big mess.

Comment: I don't want to read through your code, match it to the list of requirements and then tell you what you need to do.  I want you to state what the problem is that you're currently having, show the input and output from your program, state what the expected output is, and ask an actual question.

Comment: When you write code, start with something small an simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step, and *never add to code that doesn't work.* (Funny how they never seem to teach this in CompSci courses.) Call a legal set of 5+1 numbers a "ticket"/ Try writing a function that will generate a random legal ticket. *Independently* try writing a function that compares two tickets. Don't write anything else until both of those work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int count=0;
    bool powerball=false; // to check if powerball matches
    int luckyarr[5];      // the winning numbers
    int luckypb=rand()%30+1; //lucky pb
    cout <<"Showing result for only won Lottos\n";
    cout <<"Lucky numbers: ";
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        luckyarr[i]=rand()%70+1;
        if(i>0){                            // line 15-22 checking if the number already exists or not
            for(int m=0; m<i;m++){
                if(luckyarr[i]==luckyarr[m]){   // it compares the new number with all previous values
                    i-=2;                       // reduces i by 2 so that i++ in line 13 will make the difference =1 and new num will be generated in place of the previous num which was same
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout <<luckyarr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "Powerball: "<<luckypb<<endl;
    cout <<"Showing result for only won Lottos\n";
    int arr[5];
    int pb;
    for(int j=1; j<=1000;j++){   //running loop 10000 times as we are buying 10,000 tickets
        for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
            arr[i]=rand()%70+1;      // generating numbers for jth ticket
            if(i>0){
                for(int m=0; m<i;m++){    //chechking similar numbers
                    if(luckyarr[i]==luckyarr[m]){
                        i-=2;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int k=0;k<5;k++){
                if(arr[i]==luckyarr[k]) count++;   // counting the number of matching numbers of jth ticket
            }
        }
        pb=rand()%30+1;
        if(pb==luckypb){
            powerball=true;                 // checking if pb matches
        }

        if(count>0 || powerball){
            cout << "For Lotto no."<< j<< ": ";
            switch (count) {
                case 5:
                    if(powerball) cout <<"You have won the Jackpot.\n";
                    else cout << "You have won $1,000,000\n";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout <<"You have won $50,000\n";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout <<"You have won $7\n";
                case 2:
                    if(powerball) cout <<"You matched 2 number and powerball and have won $3\n";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if(powerball) cout <<"You matched only 1 number powerball and have won $3\n";
                    break;
                case 0:
                    if(powerball) cout <<"You matched only powerball and You have won $3\n";
                    break;
            }
            count=0;          // resetting count and pb for next ticket
            powerball=false;
        }


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your code. It took a while but it was fun :P Hope it works for you. If you don't understand anything or need any change, inbox me